# What is the proper way to add uploaded pdf files to the SSRS report by merging these pdf to the SSRS Report

Tags: c#-4.0, reporting-services, pdf-generation

Want to merge uploaded pdf at the end of SSRS report file instead of having them as Hyperlink in the SSRS report.

Answer (score 0):

I believed it is better to merge existing pdf files to an SSRS report after the SSRS report has been generated. Then you can use a free tool called PdfSharp to merge your documents together.

Sample is located here http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/concatenatedocuments-sample.ashx